# Js to Reactjs conversion

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am looking for convert this Js to ReactJS with the best practice.

```
$crisp.push(['do', 'chat:open']);
<button onclick="$crisp.push(['do', 'chat:open'])">Click Me!</button>
```

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Is `$crisp` a global variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try creating a state called `crisp` with react hooks (using functional component):

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
function MyComponent(){
        let [crisp,setCrisp] = useState([])
        function handleOnClick():
                 setCrisp(
                      [
                      ...crisp,
                       'do','chat:open'
                      ]
                    )
       return(
         <button onClick = {()=>handleOnClick()}>Click me!</button>
)
}
```